# extracting data between two semicolons in C

Tags: c, pointers, substring

I'm trying to write a utility type of function without being too complex to extract a value from semicolon separated strings. In this example, I'm trying to extract `X=bc` and what I receive instead is a segmentation fault when assigning a value to `*cpp`

What could I be doing wrong?

```
int main()
{
    char x[500]="a;X=bc;def;ghi";
    char* cp=x,*cpp;

    while ((cp=strstr(cp,";")))
    {
        cp++;

        if ((*cp)=='X' && (*cp+1)=='=')
        {
            cp+=2;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ((cpp=strstr(cp,";")))
    {
        *cpp='\0';
    }

    printf("'%s' '%s'\n",x,cp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you only want _one_ char, use strchr(cp,';') instead of strstr(cp,";").  It's much faster.

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong:

```
    if ((*cp)=='X' && (*cp+1)=='=')
```

it should be:

```
    if ((*cp)=='X' && *(cp+1)=='=')
```

or better yet:

```
    if (cp[0]=='X' && cp[1]=='=')
```

Note that the code as written is very fragile - there are many ways in which it can fail - try and get into the habit of *programming defensively* - always assume that anything that can fail will fail and write your code accordingly, so that it will at least *fail gracefully* when things don't work as expected.

Another tip, while I'm here: learn some basic debugging techniques - I couldn't immediately see what was wrong with the code so I added a few printf's to the code so that I could get more information about what was going on - it soon became apparent that `cp` was `NULL` after the first loop and from there it was easier to see the problem. Alternatively I could have just stepped through the code in a debugger - either technique would take you straight to this bug in a minute or two.

Answer (score 1):

Because you got your answer I only can show you another approach:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void checkString(char *string1, char *string2){
    char *string3;
    char *s1, *s2, *s3;

    size_t lenstring1 = strlen(string1);
    size_t lenstring2 = strlen(string2);

    if (lenstring2 < 1){
        printf("There is no substring found");
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t i=0,j=0;
    int found=0;

    s1 = string1;
    s2 = string2;


    for(i = 0; i < lenstring1; i++){
        if(*s1 == *s2){
            s3 = s1;
            for(j = 0;j < lenstring2;j++){
                if(*s3 == *s2){
                  s3++;s2++;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }

            s2 = string2;
            if(j == strlen(string2)){
                found = 1;
                string3=string2;
              }
          }
        s1++;
    }

    if(found != 0){
        printf("%s\n",string3);

    }else{
        printf("No match Found");
    }
}

int main(void){
    char string1[] = "a;X=bc;def;ghi";
    char string2[] = "X=bc";

    checkString(string1, string2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> X=bc

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using the standard library function, `strtok`, which sounds like a perfect fit for this task. It takes a string and separates it into tokens, based on the delimiter or delimiters given as a parameter.

This code should get you started :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
        char *token;
        char *parsed;
        char input[] ="a;X=bc;def;ghi";
        parsed = input;
        while(token = strtok(parsed, ";"))
        {
                parsed = NULL;
                puts(token);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The first call to `strtok` uses the actual string to be parsed as the first parameter, while the following calls use `NULL`. If there are no more tokens (or no tokens at all), `strtok` returns `NULL`.

There are a few things to keep in mind when using this function, though :

1. The prototype is `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);`. This means that `str` must be writable. As such, you must not assume that it will be left unmodified.
2. If you're ever going to use threads in your program, calling `strtok` from multiple threads will lead to bugs, since it uses global state to store the last returned token. POSIX defines a thread-safe form of this function whose prototype is `char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);`, with the last parameter used to store data between calls. With such an interface, there is no need to use global state, as `saveptr` can be stored as a local variable.

The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) for this function should answer all your further doubts.